# ngRepeat filter, Checkbox select parent child vise vesa

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

**Json**

```
$scope.tmp = {
    'ax':{
       label:'AX',
       checked:false
    },
    'by':{
       label:'BY', 
       linkTo:'ax',
       checked:false     
    },
    'xy':{
       label:'BY', 
       linkTo:'by',
       checked:false     
    }
}
```

I need to check parent if any of its child is checked and if parent is selected then child is also selected with the help of linkTo attribute.

**I have tried below code**

```
<div ng-repeat='(k,v) in tmp'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tmp[k].checked" ng-change="v.linkTo != undefined ? tmp[k].checked=tmp[v.linkeTo].checked:{tmp[k].checked = (tmp | filter : {linkTo:k}).checked }">Linked With {{obj.label}} 
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the parent checkbox?

Comment: Parent and child generated into ng-repeat but when any of parent checkbox clicked at the same time child will be checked and that logic defined  in ng-change.

Comment: can you create  a plank for it.?

Comment: @Viplock you can see demo here https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/3519/

Comment: So in your case 'ax' is parent of 'by' and 'by' is parent of 'xy' ?

Comment: Yes @vincentluth its parent of by and xy its possble with using function but i try with ng-change inline, is it possible when dynamic array key is there with filter option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a function for it , to handle change activity. Try Using this -

```
   <div ng-app ng-controller="TController">
    <div ng-repeat='(k,v) in tmp'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tmp[k].checked" ng-change="change(v.linkTo,k)">{{k}} Linked With {{v.linkTo}} <br />
    </div>
  </div>
```

And method like this

```
$scope.change=function(linkto,k){
  if(linkto!=undefined){
  $scope.tmp[linkto].checked=$scope.tmp[k].checked;
}
else{
       angular.forEach($scope.tmp, function (value, key) {

            if (value.linkTo === k) {
                value.checked=$scope.tmp[k].checked;
            }
          })

        }

    }
```

Try this [Js Fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/8atfxzsd/)

Comment: Thanks @Viplock Its working with function but its possible inline in ng-change for case of dynamic key in array using filter option.

Comment: yes you can make it inline, but if the condition is complex you should not go for inline condition, because you won't be able to fine out the mistake like typo issue , syntactical or logical  problem.